# jqueryui dialog with buttons - how to revert draggable element

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dialog, jquery-ui-sortable, confirm

I have a jquery ui dialog which is opened on drag of an element from a sortable list to another.
I want to revert the element to its previous sortable list if a specific button is clicked in the dialog.
I use 'stop' and 'recieve' events of the sortable lists, and I know there is an option to revert using sortable('cancel'), but the thing is that unlike `alert()` or `confirm()`, the dialog does not halt the execution of code, so I'm "missing" the event, and than I cannot revert the element.

In short, I want to acheive something similar to this fiddle, but to use jqueryui dialog with buttons instead of `confirm()`: 
 http://jsfiddle.net/WbHAr/1/

Comment: u can add a click event listener on that button, and write your revert logic in that.